# Testcafe aborts with ELIFECYCLE npm error and exit status 4

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I know this is the most common issue with Testcafe, but I previously posted questions and solutions doesn't match/work to resolve my issue. Testcafe version 1.8.4, with allure reporting. I have configured few test suites running sequential in my project but, after first suite run Testcafe terminates with the following error and aborts the test run.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4
npm ERR! user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure: `TARGET_ENV=test DATA_CENTER=azwus2 testcafe 'chromium:headless:emulation' './journeys/app-journeys/*-spec.js' -r allure`
npm ERR! Exit status 4
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Venkat/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T03_13_43_108Z-debug.log
Below is the debug log 
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.10.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test:appjourneys:azure'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.11.3
3 info using node@v12.10.0
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'pretest:appjourneys:azure',
4 verbose run-script   'test:appjourneys:azure',
4 verbose run-script   'posttest:appjourneys:azure'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~pretest:appjourneys:azure: user-journey-tests@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: user-journey-tests@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/Venkat/GAP/store-service/user-journeys-testcafe/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
9 verbose lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: CWD: /Users/Venkat/GAP/store-service/user-journeys-testcafe
10 silly lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   "TARGET_ENV=test DATA_CENTER=azwus2 testcafe 'chromium:headless:emulation' './journeys/app-journeys/*-spec.js' -r allure"
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: Returned: code: 4  signal: null
12 info lifecycle user-journey-tests@1.0.0~test:appjourneys:azure: Failed to exec test:appjourneys:azure script
13 verbose stack Error: user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure: `TARGET_ENV=test DATA_CENTER=azwus2 testcafe 'chromium:headless:emulation' './journeys/app-journeys/*-spec.js' -r allure`
13 verbose stack Exit status 4
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid user-journey-tests@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/Venkat/GAP/store-service/user-journeys-testcafe
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test:appjourneys:azure"
18 verbose node v12.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.11.3
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 4
22 error user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure: `TARGET_ENV=test DATA_CENTER=azwus2 testcafe 'chromium:headless:emulation' './journeys/app-journeys/*-spec.js' -r allure`
22 error Exit status 4
23 error Failed at the user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 4, true ]
```

I tried the following:

1. npm -clean install
2. update testcafe to latest version 1.8.4 3.

I merged my suite in to one single npm run `<cmd>` - This helps to run the tests but still the error continues to show up at the end and build status is unstable. Any thoughts how to over come this?

Answer (score 1):

I see the following error in the NPM log:

```
Error: user-journey-tests@1.0.0 test:appjourneys:azure: \\`TARGET_ENV=test DATA_CENTER=azwus2 testcafe 'chromium:headless:emulation' './journeys/app-journeys/*-spec.js' -r allure\\`
Exit status 4
     at EventEmitter.<anonymous>
```

It means that TestCafe finished tests with exit code 4.

TestCafe finishes with a non-zero exit code when some tests fail during your test session. In this particular case, 4 tests failed.

If you want to disable test failure indication via exit codes, you can append `|| exit 0` to the TestCafe command.